C# RX - GroupBy only runs for the first time
I have rx pipeline that does the following -

Runs every 10 second.
Generate period using Scan (1 minute increments).
Fetches data for current time period.
Projects them as stream of objects of type IEvent.
Groups then base on IEvent.Channel.
Prints the Channel.

The last step only run once. I'm expecting to run infinitely.
What am I missing here ?
var observable = Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))                
    .Scan(seed, NextPeriod)                
    .SelectMany(period =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("fetching events for");
        Console.WriteLine(period.Begin.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ffff"));
        Console.WriteLine(period.End.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.ffff"));

        var events = FetchEvents(period, eventDataProvider);
        Console.WriteLine($"{events.Count} events fetched");

        return events;
    })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Channel).Subscribe(group =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Channel - {group.Key}");
    });

Console Output
events generated

fetching events for
2024-05-15 03:16:00.0000
2024-05-15 03:16:59.0000
40 events fetched
Channel - group-1
Channel - group-2
Channel - group-3

fetching events for
2024-05-15 03:17:00.0000
2024-05-15 03:17:59.0000
1475 events fetched

fetching events for
2024-05-15 03:18:00.0000
2024-05-15 03:18:59.0000
1475 events fetched



It runs 3 times, according to your output. What am I missing?

The last print statement - where it prints the group key.

It's doing exactly what it should be doing.

Here's a stand-alone version of what you're doing:
IDisposable subscription =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
        .Take(3)
        .SelectMany(x => new[]
        {
            new { Channel = "a", Value = x, },
            new { Channel = "b", Value = x, },
            new { Channel = "c", Value = x, },
        })
        .Do(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.Channel}, {x.Value}"))
        .GroupBy(x => x.Channel)
        .Subscribe(group =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Channel - {group.Key}");
        });

The SelectMany is producing this stream of values:
a, 0
b, 0
c, 0
a, 1
b, 1
c, 1
a, 2
b, 2
c, 2

Now the GroupBy is grouping by the Channel and is producing an IObservable<IGroupedObservable<...>>. That's a nested observable. It's effectively IObservable<IObservable<...>>.
The first time it sees each channel it subscribes to the outer observable and outputs the channel's key for the first observable it sees with that key. You're not doing anything with the inner observable - so it doesn't matter how many times the inner observable returns a value - you just haven't subscribed to it.
